# Crash in Win32 App while calling "GetOpenFileName"

Tags: winapi, crash, getopenfilename

I have one win32 prog where i want to call GetOpenFileName() but every time it got crash and CommDlgExtendedError() return error code as 1008. Please help me out.

```
char Filestring[MAX_PATH] = "\0";
OPENFILENAME ofn = { 0 };
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
ofn.lpstrFile = (LPWSTR)Filestring;
ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn) == TRUE)
{

}

else
{
    int err = CommDlgExtendedError();
}
```

Comment: `(LPWSTR)Filestring` - Every cast is a lie. This one, too. It's an out-of-bounds array access waiting to happen, and a debug build (using the debug heap) just makes sure this will happen. If you want to make the immediate problem go away, use `wchar_t Filestring[MAX_PATH]` instead. If you wish to solve the problem, be explicit about using the Unicode API (e.g. `OPENFILENAMEW`, `GetOpenFileNameW`, etc.

Comment: Adding to my question in "Disassembly" it is showing as it is trying to access 0th memory location. Means, the null pointer but i did not find any , i have checked by debugging there is no null pointer. Since, i am new in this field, i apologize if any mistake is there.

Comment: Unrelated: Never check against TRUE, check for FALSE.

Comment: As already mentioned, you can't simply cast a `char*` string to `wchar_t*` and expect it to work. If you want to use the wide-char interface, declare your buffer as such: `wchar_t Filestring[MAX_PATH] = L"\0";`.

Comment: Key takeaway message is not to cast in the way you did here. Presumably you added the cast because the compiler reported a type mismatch. The cast does not change the fact that the types don't match, it just tells the compiler to ignore the error, and trust that you know better. Invariably the compiler knows better.

Comment: @AdrianMole Thank you for your solution. Here "lpstrFile" is  LPWSTR type which is typedef of  "wchar_t*". So, I can not use wchar_t.  If it is possible please put some light here.

Comment: "*Here `lpstrFile` is `LPWSTR` type which is typedef of `wchar_t*`. So, I can not use `wchar_t`*" - the fact that you just said that shows you need to brush up on the fundamentals of the C++ language. Get a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/) and strengthen your basics before you tackle the Win32 API.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Noted with thanks. I will.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `TCHAR` version of the `GetOpenFileName()` API, which maps to either the ANSI (`GetOpenFileNameA()`) or Unicode (`GetOpenFileNameW()`) API depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined.

Since `ofn.lpstrFile` is accepting a `LPWSTR` (`wchar_t*`) pointer, expecting it to point at a `wchar[]` buffer, your project clearly has `UNICODE` defined. But you are giving it a type-casted pointer to a `char[]` buffer instead, which has 1/2 the storage space than you are telling the API is available for it to write to.

Your type-cast on the `ofn.lpstrFile` field is lying to the API.  The code is calling the Unicode API, so it will write Unicode data to your `char[]` buffer, giving you [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) output, and risking a buffer overflow.

You should use a `TCHAR[]` buffer instead to match what the API is expecting, eg:

```
TCHAR Filestring[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("\0");
OPENFILENAME ofn = { 0 };
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
ofn.lpstrFile = Filestring;
ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn))
{
    ...
}
else
{
    int err = CommDlgExtendedError();
    ...
}
```

Otherwise, use the ANSI or Unicode API explicitly, depending on your desired character encoding, eg:

```
CHAR Filestring[MAX_PATH] = "\0";
OPENFILENAMEA ofn = { 0 };
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
ofn.lpstrFile = Filestring;
ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
if (GetOpenFileNameA(&ofn))
{
    ...
}
else
{
    int err = CommDlgExtendedError();
    ...
}
```

```
WCHAR Filestring[MAX_PATH] = L"\0";
OPENFILENAMEW ofn = { 0 };
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
ofn.lpstrFile = Filestring;
ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
if (GetOpenFileNameW(&ofn))
{
    ...
}
else
{
    int err = CommDlgExtendedError();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried everything but getting the same error. When i called it from "InitInstance" it is working fine. But getting error if i called it from "WndProc".

Comment: You're creating a popup dialog in `WndProc`? So, in response to a particular message? That's not how to do things.

Comment: @prod 1008 is not a typical error code that `CommDlgExtendedError()` would return. After making the suggested changes, if you are still getting an error then please edit your question to provide a [mcve] that reproduces the error.

Comment: @AdrianMole  Thank you for your patience. I will restructure my code.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau  Thank you for your patience. I will restructure my code.